# sqlite not honoring primary key in table definition. Lookups failing

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, lookup

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE tz ('id' INT(4),'name' TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

403|Pacific/Honolulu
404|Pacific/Kanton
405|Pacific/Kiritimati
406|Pacific/Kosrae
407|Pacific/Kwajalein
408|Pacific/Majuro
409|Pacific/Marquesas
410|Pacific/Midway
```

It's not working as expected. When I try to look up based on id it works:

```
sqlite> select * from tz where id = 10;
10|Africa/Brazzaville
```

But when I try to lookup on the primary key it doesn't:

```
sqlite> select * from tz where name = 'Pacific/Rarotonga';
*nothing*
```

Seems like it should work but it isn't.
What's going on ?

Comment: I can't reproduce (as expected - the sql is completely normal). Perhaps there is something weird like a non-printing character in the text or something in the encoding?

Comment: just for kicks - try: `select * from tz where name like '%Australia%Sydney%'`

Comment: @topsail: Process of elimination shows it is some kind of trailing noise.  'Australia/Sydney%'

Answer (score 1):

Per @topsail's suggestion that the data wasn't what I thought it was, I did the following and see two trailing LF characters I don't want, so I'll have to clean the data up before inserting it.

```
sqlite3 db.db "select name from tz where id = 10" | hexdump -C
00000000  41 66 72 69 63 61 2f 42  72 61 7a 7a 61 76 69 6c  |Africa/Brazzavil|
00000010  6c 65 0a 0a                                       |le..|
00000014
```